# Blazor Server: CascadingAuthenticationState unequal GetAuthenticationStateAsync()

Tags: authentication, authorization, asp.net-identity, blazor-server-side

Can anybody help me solve a

problem of **CascadingAuthenticationState** and **GetAuthenticationStateAsync()**:

by executing the following in a Blazor Server 5.0 Application,
i get the following results:

```
@inject CustomAuthStateProvider AuthenticationStateProvider 

[CascadingParameter] 
private Task<AuthenticationState> authenticationStateTask { get; set; }
```

1. 

```
AuthenticationState authenticationState = await authenticationStateTask; 
bool IsAuthenticated = authenticationState.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated; // ---> False
```

2. 

```
HttpContextAccessor httpContext = new(); 
IsAuthenticated = httpContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated; // ---> True
```

3. 

```
authenticationState = await AuthenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync(); 
IsAuthenticated = authenticationState.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;  // ---> True
```

Why the authenticationStateTask of the CascadingAuthenticationState in 1) result is false ?

Although AuthenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync() is true ??

I've implemented a CustomAuthStateProvider:

```
public class CustomAuthStateProvider : ServerAuthenticationStateProvider 
    { 
        public override Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync() 
        { 
            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(new[] 
            { 
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "exampleuser"), 
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Surname, "Mouse"), 
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.GivenName, "Micky"), 
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "testRole"), 
            }, "user authentication type"); 
            var user = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity); 
            return Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(user)); 
        } 
        public void NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged() 
        { 
            NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(GetAuthenticationStateAsync()); 
        } 
    }
```

Startup.cs:

```
 //services.AddAuthorization(); 
services.AddAuthorizationCore(); 

services.AddScoped<CustomAuthStateProvider>(); 
services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider>(provider => provider.GetRequiredService<CustomAuthStateProvider>())
services.AddScoped<IHostEnvironmentAuthenticationStateProvider>(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<CustomAuthStateProvider>());
```

After the successful Login:

```
HostAuthentication.SetAuthenticationState(Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(principal)));
```

App.razor:

```
<CascadingAuthenticationState> 
    <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly" PreferExactMatches="@true"> 
        <Found Context="routeData"> 
            <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" /> 
        </Found> 
        <NotFound> 
            <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)"> 
                <p>Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p> 
            </LayoutView> 
        </NotFound> 
    </Router> 
</CascadingAuthenticationState>
```

Using the AuthenticationStateProvider instead of the CustomAuthStateProvider works fine !

Thanks for your help !!!
Kind regards
Jojo2109